# How do I print colored ANSI characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, colors, flask-restful

I'm developing an API with Flask and flask_restful and a matching CLI for a project I'm working on and have now faced something I can't get rid of. On the API side, when I get a request on a certain endpoint, I use the [PrettyTable](https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/) library for building a colored table on terminal. I'm building the table as follows:

```
t = PrettyTable([ Color.CGREEN2 + 'Username' + Color.CEND,
                  Color.CGREEN2 + 'Dataset'  + Color.CEND,
                  Color.CGREEN2 + 'Files' + Color.CEND])
for ds in db.getAllDatasets( username ):
  t.add_row(  [username, ds.dataset, len(ds.files)] )
return t.__str__()
```

I've tried to return the *t* object, but it wasn't JSON serializable. By calling the *__str__* method I was able to return it successfully, but just can't print the output properly on my terminal. The code I'm using for that is:

```
try:
  r = requests.post(url='http://my-server:my-port/my-endpoint', data=data)
  print (str(r.text))
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
  MSG_ERROR (self, "Failed to connect to LPS Cluster.")
```

And the output I get is:

```
"+----------+---------+-------+\n| \u001b[92mUsername\u001b[0m | \u001b[92mDataset\u001b[0m | \u001b[92mFiles\u001b[0m |\n+----------+---------+-------+\n+----------+---------+-------+"
```

It's possible to see that the characters are on the right place and it should work, but it doesn't.

I guess it may have something to do with those quotation marks both on beginning and ending of the string, but I'm not sure and don't know what to do about it.

Can you guys help me get it right?

Comment: If it's already a string then printing its representation is not necessary.

Comment: Actually, it's a <prettytable.PrettyTable object>

Comment: which version of pretty tables are you using?

Comment: I've noticed it has a _get_string()_ method, but it gets to the same output.

Comment: It's version 0.7.2

Comment: From looking briefly at the examples I think you should just `print` it, not convert to string. (Ed.) Ah wait. You are already destroying its PrettyTableness by explicitly using only its `str` result...

Comment: Try `return t.get_string()` or `print(r.get_string()`.

Comment: @usr2564301 I can't return the object as it's not JSON serializable.

Comment: @martineau the `get_string` method leads me to same result

Comment: Then my first comment goes. It is no longer a PrettyTable, it's a simple string. Hence, no need to force to its representation.

Comment: Yeah, right, it's a string now. My issue is with printing the string by interpreting those special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way of fixing it. On the API side, I turn the response into JSON by doing:

```py
return jsonify(
    error_code=HTTPStatus.OK,
    message=t.get_string()
)
```

instead of my previous `return t.__str__()`.

After that, on the CLI, I do:

```py
print (r.json()['message'])
```

and it works like a charm!

Thanks everybody.